# field is hidden behind entry xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

I've created an autoComplete entry class which creates an entry with a listview that auto-completes places :

```
AutoCompleteEntry pickupPoint = new AutoCompleteEntry { HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.StartAndExpand, HeightRequest = 50 } ;
```

I put the AutoCompleteEntry in a stackView like so :

```
 var topStack = new StackLayout { Children = { pickupPoint, time_field }, Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal,  };
        var mainStack = new StackLayout
        {
            Children = {
                        title,
                        topStack,
                        drop_off_field,
                        comment_field,
                        connectWithALocal,
                        submitBtn
                    },
            Padding = 20,
            Spacing = 10
        };
```

The listView of the autoCompleteEntry is not visible as the drop off-field hides it. you can see in this picture: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uMB4Q.png . I know that in stack layout the Z-Index is controlled by the way the items are ordered but I need the pickUpPoint (AutoCompleteEntry) to come before the drop-off point. Is my only solution an Absolute layout or am I missing something?

Comment: you have `pickupPoint` nested inside of another StackLayout, so its dropdown is being constrained by the size of that layout.  Try removing the inner StackLayout.  You'll have to move `time_field` for this to work.

Comment: Set the  `VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand` of `mainStack` .